# VIew not found on double clicking the button for the first time

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-core, button

I have three buttons on each form. "Search/Save", "Reset" and "Export to excel". Every time the page  loads for the first time after I run the website, and I double click on the "Export to excel" button, I get error saying "View not found".
I am calling jQuery on button click. Here is the code:

cshtml:

```html
<input type="button" value="Search" class="btn_search btn" id="RunsheetSearchBtn" aria-invalid="false">
<input type="button" value="Reset" class="btn_add btn" id="RunsheetResetBtn" />
<input type="button" disabled value="Export To Excel" class="btn-success btn" id="RunsheetExcelBtn" />
```

jQuery:

```js
$("#RunsheetDtlsExcelBtn").click(function () {
    var vw_DeliveryById = $('#vw_DeliveryById').val();
    var vw_FreightHandlerId = $('#vw_FreightHandlerId').val();

    $('#tbl_tmpfrm').remove();
    var frmstr = '<form id="tbl_tmpfrm" method="post" action="/Booking/RunsheetDtlsExportToExcel">';
    frmstr += '<input type="hidden" name="vw_DeliveryById" value="' + vw_DeliveryById + '"/>';
    frmstr += '<input type="hidden" name="vw_FreightHandlerId" value="' + vw_FreightHandlerId + '"/>';
    frmstr += '</form>';
    $('body').append(frmstr);
    $('#tbl_tmpfrm').submit();
});

$('.btn-add-runsheet').click(function () {
    window.location.href = '/Booking/RunsheetInsUpd';
});
```

I was planning to prevent double click on the button, however, I was wondering what is causing this error. And is preventing double click a correct solution?

Comment: Please check the shared code, by using the JQuery scripts, we can't find the related elements based on the JQuery selector (there are using different `class` or `id` value). But from your javascript scripts, it seems that you are using two methods (submit the form and set the location.href property methods) to redirect to another page, you could set a break point in this function and check whether the issue is related it, please verify it.

Comment: To prevent the double click event, you could use the `event.preventDefault();` in the button click event and set the button `disabled` attribute to `true`. Code like this: `$(document).ready(function () { $("#submit").one('click', function (event) {   event.preventDefault();  //do something   $(this).prop('disabled', true);});
});`